# residual degree in $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})$ (i.e. the decomposition field of $X^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$). I want to compute the residual degree of $3$ in $K$.

Here is how I proceeded : We know that $3$ is inert in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ so I said let's consider the decomposition of $3\mathbb{Z}[i]$ in $K$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]/3\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{F}_9$ I just checked that $X^4-2$ has four distinct roots in $\mathbb{F}_9$ and concluded that $3\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has residual degree $1$ in $K$ hence $3$ has residual degree $2$ in $K$.

My question is, if what I did is correct, how can we justify that we can use this technique (i.e. looking at the factorisation of $X^4-2$ in $\mathbb{F}_9$) and if it is not correct what should we do to compute the residual degree ?

I also did the same thing with $7$ and again found that $X^4-2$ has $4$ roots is $\mathbb{F}_{49}$ and so concluded that $7$ has residual degree $2$ so i'm also wondering if that was ok although I guess I should be able to infer from the answer for $3$.

Comment: What's the definition of residual degree?